# Google map API displaying marker location in an infowindow

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a javascript array of locations (jarray), which I am looping over and adding a marker of each location onto a google map.  Along with those markers I would like to add an infowindow displaying the marker's location.  The code below displays the same latitude and longitude location in each of marker's infowindows.  I would like for each marker to have its own address in its infowindow.  I have also tried setting the content of the infowindow to results[0].geometry.location, address, and jarray[i] all to no success.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < jarray.length; i++){
                            geocoder.geocode({'address': jarray[i]}, 
                            function(results, status) {
                              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

                                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: "Marker",
                                    icon: image
                                  });

                                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: "<p>"+marker.position+"</p>"
                                  });

                                  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                  });
```

Comment: [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/d0ygococ/), although I wouldn't recommend using undocumented promerties (`marker.position`), use the documented method (`marker.getPosition()`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a google maps api marker has a location property - you can use position - the method is marker.getPosition()

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Marker

You can then use that position to an address by usign the geocoding (if you need that)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: I changed it to position.  Every marker though is getting the same latitude and longitude coordinates in their infowindows.  I would like for each marker to have its own position in its infowindow.

Comment: I have made edits to the above description and code.

Comment: If every marker shows in a different position on the map then they have different positions.

your problem might be something else.
Maybe try logging what's loading to get more information (console.log(marker))

Comment: Well each marker displays in the correct position on the map so I know the address is right.  They just all have the same infowindows.

Comment: do you know if they all use the position of a particular maker (the last or the first ?)

since it looks to me like your posted code is missing some } and ) then it's hard to debug it for you. but if it's only using the last one, it probably means youre accidentally creating only one infowindow, or something like that....

Comment: That sounds like the problem.  I think each the last infowindow created is the only one displaying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

insted of marker.location, use the jarray location itself. You can adapt this code to suit you since I dont know the contents of your jarray.

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   infowindow.setContent(jarray[i]['lat'] +" " + jarray[i]['lat']);
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                  });
```

Comment: The jarray is just an array of street address locations.  I tried that way, and nothing displays in the infowindows.

Comment: oops, I thought it had the geo locations on it itself, sorry about that